# DC electric motor model

Tags: dc-motor

In the paper "The study on electromagnetic compatibility of DC electric motor in HAPS" there is a description for a DC motor model structure :
[image]

[image]

My problem is with imaging this model as I can't understand, and therefore, imagine this model, specifically the louvers part as it is not illustrated in the figure. Someone, please provide some pictures to illustrate this model. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The louvers are for cooling.  And what's drawn isn't what I'd call "louvers" -- I think of louvers as slots, not little bitty holes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much , Can you please explain this statemnt "3 louvers × 8 group, interval dl of every louver in a group, 45◦ interval of the group along the circumferential"  I really appreciate your help !

Comment: Ok I understood the statement. One more question please, what about the horizontal lines drawn in the inner cylinders ?? Are they louvers ? as he said that there exist louvers in the gap between the shell and the axis?

Comment: I don't think they're saying there are louvers between the shell and the shaft.  Rather, I think that they are modeling the assembly as having a gap between the shell and shaft.  Remember, this model is meant to vastly simplify a motor into something that they can use for modeling it's RF behavior.

Comment: Those horizontal lines denote that the 3D model has been sliced across the middle.  They essentially mean "this area is filled with stuff".